# Return all node or relationship properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to get all properties off a node or a relationship without explicitly naming them?
Something like

```
START a=node(1), b=node(2)
CREATE a-[r:RELATED]-b
RETURN r.*
```

or

```
START a=node(1)
RETURN a.properties
```

These I tried unsuccessfully and I can't find a method in the cypher documentation. I guess that is because there is no way, but it would be good to know either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
START a=node(1), b=node(2)
CREATE a-[r:RELATED]-b
RETURN r
```

Returns the relationship with all its properties.

Comment: For me that returns a relationship JSON–object with a reference to its properties' URL. I then have to send a second request to get the properties.

Comment: Oh no! You are absolutely right, it does also return the properties, they are just rather deeply nested, so I didn't find them. Thank you!